# ngTransclude not wrapping content at all

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I have a custom angular directive that goes in several of my views in angularjs.  The directive is set to transclude but none of the wrapped content shows up.

```
app.directive('card', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      sysStack: "=",
      cardname: "@"
    },
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'partials/directives/card.html',
    replace:true
  }
}]);
```

card.html looks like this

```
<section class="card" ng-transclude>

</section>
```

The css styles this section tag to be a flexbox with a drop shadow and a slight background color, which displays perfectly as expected, but none of the content it wraps shows up, nor do the attributes passed along its scope.  My test is just something like this in one of my views.

```
<card sys-stack="2" cardname="test">
    testing 123
</card>
```

testing 123 doesn't show up, and the attributes don't even seem to exist on the dom at all.  The flexbox section rendered by the card directive show up fine as I said, but not any of the wrapped content.  Can someone help me understand what's going on here?

**I have updated my question for clarity**

---

The card.html renders in the dom fine, just not any of the attached attributes or anything it wraps.

Comment: What are the contents of `partials/directives/card.html` ?

Comment: are you sure http://jsbin.com/cukeseririyu/1/ please double check path to your template

Comment: The card.html renders in the dom without an issue, but nothing it wraps renders, and none of the attached attributes do either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I feel like an idiot.  I checked and double checked my paths, but what I didn't realize is that I have a directive called servicedesk, and a view called servicedesk.  I will need to fix that.  I was adding content to the directive, meanwhile the view also had the card directive, but no content within it.  Sorry again.